# "Unspecified Error" 80004005 when creating new Access database, only on another workstation

Tags: jscript, office-automation, wsh

What I have is a JScript file that gets called by `cscript`, and this script is a proof-of-concept that creates a new Access 2007 format database, imports a set of VBA modules into the database, and then runs a subroutine from the imported modules.

This script works flawlessly on my own computer. I have Office 2013 installed. However, I brought this script over to a coworker's machine and had him attempt running it. On his machine, we get an error that looked something like, `createdb.js (22, 1): Unspecified error` and the error code is 80004005. My code, below:

```js
'use strict';

/**
 * AcNewDatabaseFormat Enumeration
 * Used with the NewCurrentDatabase method to specify the database format of the newly created database.
 */
var acModule = 5,
    dbText = 10,
    acNewDatabaseFormat = {
        UserDefault: 0,
        Access2000: 9,
        Access2002: 10,
        Access12: 12
    };

var fs = new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject');
var access = new ActiveXObject('Access.Application');
var basePath = fs.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName);
var db, prop, vcsFolder, fCur, module;

//Create DB and set up some superficial things.
access.NewCurrentDatabase(basePath + '\\ImportTest.accdb', acNewDatabaseFormat.Access12, null, "", "");
//access.OpenCurrentDatabase(basePath + '\\ImportTest.accdb');
db = access.CurrentDb();
prop = db.CreateProperty('AppTitle', dbText, 'My New Database');
db.Properties.Append(prop);
prop = db.CreateProperty('StartUpForm', dbText, 'Main Form');
db.Properties.Append(prop);
db.Properties('UseMDIMode') = 1;

//Add MSAccess-VCS modules
vcsFolder = fs.GetFolder(basePath + '\\MSAccess-VCS');
fCur = new Enumerator(vcsFolder.files);
for (; !fCur.atEnd(); fCur.moveNext()) {
    module = fCur.item().Name.replace('.bas', '');
    access.LoadFromText(acModule, module, fCur.item());
}

access.Run('ImportAllSource');
access.Quit();
```

Line 22, character 1 is `access.NewCurrentDatabase(basePath + '\\ImportTest.accdb', acNewDatabaseFormat.Access12, null, "", "");`. Office (and Access!) 2007 is installed on his machine. We tried other `AcNewDatabaseFormat`s with no luck. What could possibly be the issue here?

Comment: Clearly you have no write access to wherever `basePath` is located.

Comment: I thought that too. BUT, we're copying the folder down to their desktops and when the folder is copied, the current user becomes the owner of the folder and the files within. They're able to modify the scripts and create new files through the New option on the context menu in the copied folder, so clearly we have write access to `basePath`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're not using any of the optional parameters, just leave them off:

```
access.NewCurrentDatabase(basePath + '\\ImportTest.accdb', acNewDatabaseFormat.Access12);
```

You only need to specify a value for optional parameters if there are other parameters you want to use later in the argument list.

Comment: Thank you! And now in true "Access is out to screw me" fashion, now it's telling me that it can't find the procedure I'm telling it to Run() on my coworker's machine! But, that's an issue for another question - this particular problem was solved.