# Access Application.Run "Can't Find The Procedure" only on another workstation

Tags: jscript, office-automation, wsh

Coming in off my last question (["Unspecified Error" 80004005 when creating new Access database, only on another workstation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30821983/))...

Again, I have Office 2013 installed, my coworker has Access 2007. My script below creates a new Access database through automation, imports a series of VBA modules from text, then runs a sub found in one of the imported modules. The script runs fine on my machine, but on my coworker's machine it says `Microsoft Office Access can't find the procedure 'ImportAllSource.'` We've also tried prefixing the name of the procedure with the name of the module it lives in (`"VCS_ImportExport.ImportAllSource"`), and the name of the project as it appears in the VBE environment (`"ImportTest.ImportAllSource"`), but with no luck and the same error.

Revised script:

```
'use strict';

/**
 * AcNewDatabaseFormat Enumeration
 * Used with the NewCurrentDatabase method to specify the database format of the newly created database.
 */
var acModule = 5,
    dbText = 10,
    acNewDatabaseFormat = {
        UserDefault: 0,
        Access2000: 9,
        Access2002: 10,
        Access12: 12
    };

var fs = new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject');
var access = new ActiveXObject('Access.Application');
var basePath = fs.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName);
var db, prop, vcsFolder, fCur, module;

//Create DB and set up some superficial things.
access.NewCurrentDatabase(basePath + '\\ImportTest.accdb', acNewDatabaseFormat.Access12);
db = access.CurrentDb();
prop = db.CreateProperty('AppTitle', dbText, 'IG IMI Database');
db.Properties.Append(prop);
prop = db.CreateProperty('StartUpForm', dbText, 'Main Switchboard');
db.Properties.Append(prop);
db.Properties('UseMDIMode') = 1;

//Add MSAccess-VCS modules
vcsFolder = fs.GetFolder(basePath + '\\MSAccess-VCS');
fCur = new Enumerator(vcsFolder.files);
for (; !fCur.atEnd(); fCur.moveNext()) {
    module = fCur.item().Name.replace('.bas', '');
    access.LoadFromText(acModule, module, fCur.item());
}

access.Run('ImportAllSource');
access.Quit();
```

Comment: Are you sure the module is getting loaded?

Comment: I'll double-check it but I'm about 90% sure I looked in the VBE for the generated database and saw the modules there, all loaded.

Comment: Just curious if _you_ have access to those module files but your coworker does not. Have him login on your PC (with Office 2013) and try. That'll tell you if it's user- or PC/Office-related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had an epiphany. The problem was some code in the loaded modules - namely, a couple `Declare` statements using the `PtrSafe` keyword. It's valid syntax in Access 2013, but not in 2007.

So, if there's an error with the VBA code in a loaded module, Access will play dumb when you try to invoke `Application.Run`.